# Calculate tangent Space in FragmentShader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to calculate the tangentspace in GLSL.

Here is the important part from my code:

```
// variables passed from vertex to fragment program //
in vec3 vertexNormal;
in vec2 textureCoord;
in vec3 lightPosition;
in vec3 vertexPos;
in mat4 modelView;
in mat4 viewMatrix;

// TODO: textures for color and normals //
uniform sampler2D normal;
uniform sampler2D texture;


// this defines the fragment output //
out vec4 color;

void main() {
 // ###### TANGENT SPACE STUFF ############
    vec4 position_eye = modelView * vec4(vertexPos,1.0);
    vec3 q0 = dFdx(position_eye.xyz);
    vec3 q1 = dFdy(position_eye.xyz);
    vec2 st0 = dFdx(textureCoord.st);
    vec2 st1 = dFdy(textureCoord.st);

    float Sx = ( q0.x * st1.t - q1.x * st0.t) / (st1.t * st0.s - st0.t * st1.s);
    float Tx = (-q0.x * st1.s + q1.x * st0.s) / (st1.t * st0.s - st0.t * st1.s);

    q0.x = st0.s * Sx + st0.t * Tx;
    q1.x = st1.s * Sx + st1.t * Tx;

    vec3 S = normalize( q0 * st1.t - q1 * st0.t);
    vec3 T = normalize(-q0 * st1.s + q1 * st0.s);

    vec3 n = texture2D(normal,textureCoord).xyz;
    n = smoothstep(-1,1,n);

    mat3 tbn = (mat3(S,T,n));

 // #######################################

n = tbn * n; // transfer the read normal to worldSpace;


vec3 eyeDir = - (modelView * vec4(vertexPos,1.0)).xyz;

vec3 lightDir =   (modelView * vec4(lightPosition.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
```

After this code there is a phong shading which will be mixed with the texture. Applying the shaders to a normal texture without normalMapping everything works fine. 
I need to calculate this in the shader for later other dynamic parts.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

This is how it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: Why are you passing `modelView`, `viewMatrix`, and `lightPosition`, when those should be *constant* for an object? They should be *uniforms*, not inputs.

Comment: Where are your `#version` directive?

Comment: As there is a lot of code before the one I've posted, I left it out.
The version is 330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

You're trying to compute the tangent-space basis matrix in your shader; that's what's wrong. You can't actually do that.

`dFdx/y` computes the rate-of-change of the given value, locally in screen-space, across the surface of a primitive. In other words, it computes the derivative of the given value over the primitive. Your input values are linearly interpolated.

The derivative of a line is a *constant*. And **line**ar interpolation produces **line**ar results. Therefore, every fragment from each primitive will get the *same derivative* for the inputs/outputs. Therefore, every fragment will compute the *same* S and T values, since they're based entirely on the derivatives.

That's why you're getting a faceted surface: two of the three matrix components will be identical across a triangle's surface.

Your computation doesn't work because it *can't* work. You're going to have to do what everyone else does: calculate the NBT matrix offline and pass them as per-vertex attributes. Or use some known property of the mesh to compute them. But this? It isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks - Therefore I have to calculate it in C++ and pass as uniform

Comment: Tangent space derivation in the pixel shader needs to still use the vertex normal, and do a Gram-Schmidt othogonalization with it, in order for the surface to be smooth. Thus, I slightly disagree with @Nicol Bolas: OP can still do that, he is just missing a bit.